# Knight-Enchanter's Readings

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

How can I find the Knights enchanter readings? Ive been to Val Royeaux. No merchants sell them. My trainer is awaiting me to finish her first command... retrieve the writings on knight-enchanter methods.

Comment: You need to put what game you are talking about in the question.  We're not psychic, and one of the points of this site is for people to find questions/answers with google.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Putting the game title in the question is not necessary if it is tagged properly. I know it wasn't initially (which is probably why you commented), but having the right tag is more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

Each one of your potential party members corresponds to a certain specialization. The readings will appear in Val Royeaux if and only if you either have not recruited that member, or have kicked that member out of the Inquisition.

The party members and their respective specializations are as follows:

- **Warrior**

  - Blackwall - Champion
  - Cassandra - Templar
  - Iron Bull - Reaver
- **Rogue**

  - Varric - Artificer
  - Sera - Tempest
  - Cole - Assassin
- **Mage**

  - Vivienne - Knight-Enchanter
  - Solas - Rift Mage
  - Dorian - Necromancer

Thus, you should find the Knight-Enchanter readings next to Vivienne. She is on the second floor of the Skyhold main hall.